# SQL Operator presedence

Tags: sql, sql-server, operator-precedence

How

```
SELECT 80/9*9
```

results `72` in SQL Server.

I followed the below link but I am getting a different answer.
[RedGate](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators001.htm)

Comment: Although you've linked to the Oracle docs, the Microsoft docs would say much the same. `/` and `*` have equal precedence so they're (effectively) evaluated left-to-right. What leads you to think that something different is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Juergen says, they have the same precedence and with [integer division](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it does:

```
80/9 = 8 (as the remainder/decimal part is removed)
```

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.

Then:

```
8 * 9 = 72
```

Answer (score 2):

`80 / 9` yields `8`. As both operands are integer, so is the result. `/` and `*` have the same precedence, so the expression is evaluated from left to right:

```
   80 / 9 * 9
-> 8 * 9
-> 72
```

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical Operators has the same precedence in SQL as in math.

Your query result in 72 because of implicit convertion :

```
80 / 9
```

Will result in 8, since the left value is an integer, so although you expect a result of double, the optimizer is implicitly casting the value into an integer.

You can "override" the the implicit casting by using a left double value:

```
80.0 / 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `*` and `/` have [the **same** precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (2) it is processed from left to right one by one.

Answer (score 0):

When two operators in an expression have the same operator precedence level, they are evaluated left to right based on their position in the expression. Here both * and / have same level of precedence.